# Some sort of Lymantriidae caterpillar?

Tags: entomology, species-identification

I found this larva in Sweden in July. It was about 15 mm long. It reminded me of *Orgyia antiqua* that I've seen before, but smaller and with a somewhat different colouration.
[image]

[image]

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lymantria_dispar_dispar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's indeed a young, and possibly worn, specimen of *[Orgyia antiqua](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orgyia_antiqua)* (also Rusty Tussock Moth or Vapourer, see also [UKmoths](http://ukmoths.org.uk/species/orgyia-antiqua/)). This species is relatively common in large parts of Sweden. However, the tufts and "tail" are usually more pronounced, but there is probably intra-species variation, and old, worn individuals can have sparser tufts. As you say, they are usually longer than 1.5cm but there is large variation, sexual dimorphism and younger larvae (early instars) are natually smaller.

[image]
(picture from wikipedia)

Swedish specimen:
[image]
( from http://krypinaturen.se/fjarilar-lepidoptera/nattfjarilar/tofsspinnare-lymantriidae/orgyia_antiqua_1878_20130626/)

*Lymantria dispar* is rather rare in Sweden and is only found in certain localities in the south (Blekinge, Småland coast) along with Öland and Gotland.

Comment: It's so hard when they don't look like perfect representatives of their species! But this sounds convincing enough. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This caterpillar is known as ***Lymantria*** ***dispar*** ***dispar***. Not to be confused with the ***Lymantria*** ***dispar***, as the ***Lymantria*** ***dispar*** ***dispar*** is the classified as it's subspecies for the sake of further taxonomy. The ***Lymantria*** ***dispar*** ***dispar***, is locale to Europe and North America (via migration), the latter being sourced in Asia. They only possess a minor (however it's deemed as rather significant in the **animalia** kingdom) difference - the female Asian Gypsy moth can fly!

In the contrary, The U. S. Department of Agriculture, defines the Asian Gypsy moth by means of flight capability partially ignoring location; "any biotype of ***Lymantria*** ***dispar*** possessing female flight capability". Which demonstrates the evident flair in confusion on this topic.

The difference in the moths visual appearance in comparison to the pictures of species you'd more commonly see (i.e. the color of its head), is possibly due to the stage of maturation of the Caterpillar or the present season. That's just my hypothesis though, i am unaware of any evidence to back that up.

Here are some further images:
http://www.papillon-poitou-charentes.org/Lymantria-dispar-Linnaeus-1758,4446.html

Reference to the facts:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lymantria_dispar_dispar

**(Edit: I was proved incorrect! However, this information would be useful for others who seek the answer!)**

Comment: Are you sure? They don't look alike to me. :-/

Comment: I'm fairly certain... not all from the species look identical just like, zebras don't all have the same distribution of stripes. It's difficult to say with 100% certainty since, nothing looks exactly  same!  Sorry, if this sounds sloppy - I'm very tired :P

Comment: I think that's incorrect. The OP's caterpillar has dorsal tussocks on segments 4, 5, 6 and 12 (or abdominal segments 1, 2, 3, and 9.) Yours has none. That's a big mismatch. Note, I didn't find a match yet, either.

Comment: Also, do you have any idea why my answer on another health post is being classed as 'spam'? I followed the advice posted on getting past this issue but to no prevail?

Comment: I have absolutely no idea then... However, I'm 100% certain that it's from  the genus 'lymantria' - feel free to check through the 220 other species of that genus ;) I apologise for my mistake.

Comment: No apology necessary; this one is clearly out of my league as well. Regarding your "spam" answer, I can't see it (I'm not a mod on this site.) You can ask about it in meta, though.

Comment: So it was a harder question than I thought! Thanks for the input, anyway, I'll keep looking...